# Mailchimp multilingual capabilities

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, mailchimp

I'm having a simple WordPress installation with pages in two languages. I want a different signup-form for each language so they get the error/confirmation in their language, and I can send them a correct newsletter.

- I tried the Mailchimp WordPress plugin, but is does't support anything that look like multilanguage. You can translate some strings, but not for 2 languages at once. It is just one language.
- MailChimp claims to detect the users language. But it doesn't. If you click on a subscribed user, the 'language' field is always empty.

  - I tried to build my own form with a 'language' field. But this field cannot be added when embedding a form.
  - Even if I could add the field, I can't translate the embedded form, or just create 2 forms. You can translate whatever you want in the form builder, but once you try to embed the form, you have to pick one Language.

I'm puzzled, I'm I missing something? What's the point of sending emails to a user if you can't talk to them in their own language?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, the MailChimp signup forms are translated based on the user's browser language. That's a different thing from what language you send their emails in.

If you're offering translations of your email (this is not something any ESP does, as far as I know), you'll probably want your subscribers to be able to choose what language to receive the email in. I'd add that as an interest group for whatever languages you plan to write emails in.